# How can i know if a user has been removed from firebase authentication Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a code that tells me if a user is logged in with firebase, but if I delete the user from firebase, the user keeps leaving.

```
try{
  var user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  if(user != null){
      _id = user.uid;
      _email = user.email;
      _name = user.displayName;
      _photo = user.photoUrl;
      this._initialRoute = 'InitialPage';
  } else{
    this._initialRoute = 'SignIn';
  }
} catch(error){
  this._initialRoute = 'SignIn';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Authentication client gets an ID token for the user, that is valid for one hour. Before that ID token expires (about 55 minutes after it is generated), the client tries to refresh the token. If the token can't be refreshed (for example: if you've deleted or disabled the account), the user will no longer be signed in on the client.

You can use an [`onAuthStateChanged` listener](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/onAuthStateChanged.html) to detect when this (and any other authentication state change) happens.

---

If you want the client to know of the change before that, you will have to use another mechanism to communicate the change. For example, it is quite common to also store the user profile in a database, such as Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database, and have the client listen to that too. You can update that database when you disable the user profile, and then (thanks to the realtime listeners of these databases) the update will be known on the client almost instantly.

---

If you also want to prevent the user from making any changes on the server once you delete/disable their account, you'll need to do that yourself. Their ID token is valid until it expires and can't be individually revoked, as that would sort'of defeat the purpose of such a bearer token.

So you'll typically also want to check against the user profile that you stored in the database, for example in the security rules of your databae.